# FAILURE: APK Build failed

Tags: android, apk

How to sort out the issue?

```
> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.2-6197926-windows Daemon #10: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.2-6197926-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.2-6197926-windows Daemon #8: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.2-6197926-windows Daemon #9: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.2-6197926-windows Daemon #11: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.2-6197926-windows Daemon #12: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.2-6197926-windows Daemon #13: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.2-6197926-windows Daemon #14: Daemon startup failed
        Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 32s
6 actionable tasks: 6 executed
```

Answer (score 0):

Android Gradle plugin 3.5 and newer on Windows requires the Windows Universal C Runtime Library. you need to  Install it